# How to write a vuex store using typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, store, vuex

I'm using the latest version of Vue & Vuex.  In Vue 2.5 there have been some added support for typescript but I can't seem to figure out how to get vuex working when I change all my vuex store js files to ts.

Does anyone have a sample project that would show me how to write a vuex store in typescript rather than javascript?

Comment: I've made an alternative library to replace vuex, which is typescript friendly, and to be honest, I think it's by far a better solution than vuex https://github.com/raizam/vue-shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding and using the following sample project:

https://github.com/hmexx/vue_typescript_starter_kit